# Why foreachPartition function make duplicate invocation to map function for every message ? (Spark 2.0.2)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the following sequence of Spark Java API calls (Spark 2.0.2):

1. Kafka stream that is processed via a map function, which return the string value from tuple2._2() for JavaDStream as in

return tuple2._2();

2. The returned JavaDStream is then processed by foreachPartition, which is wrapped by foreachRDD.
3. foreachPartition's call function does Iterator inputParams.next ();

When data is received, step 1 is executed, which is correct. However, inputParams.next () in step 3 makes a duplicate call to the map function in step 1. So that map function is called twice for every message: the first time when the message is received from the Kafka stream, and the second time when Iterator inputParams.next () is invoked from foreachPartition's call function.

I also tried transforming the data  as in

public TestTransformedClass call(Tuple2 tuple2) for step 1

public void call(Iterator inputParams) for step 3

and the same issue occurs. So this issue occurs, no matter whether this sequence of Spark API calls involve data transformation or not.

Questions:

1. Since the message was already processed in step 1, why does inputParams.next () in step 3 makes a duplicate call to the map function in step 1 ?
2. How do I fix it to avoid duplicate invocation for every message ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `cache()` before foreachRDD?

Comment: I had not. I tried cache() before foreachRDD, and it resolves this issue. Thank you for this suggestion. 

On a side note,  documentation on cache(),   foreachRDD, and foreachPartition does not indicate that cache() is needed for foreachRDD, and foreachPartition not to make duplicate calls to map function. So I wonder if this is a bug in Spark lazy instantiation framework.

Comment: Tomorrow I will write answer with explanation :)

Comment: T. Gawenda, per your previous response, could you explain why cache() is needed in this case and why it is not a bug in Spark's lazy instantiation framework ? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I didn't have time. I will post answer as soon as it's possible :)

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't able to reproduce it on simple case with socket stream. I was thinking that it is caused by RDD laziness. If you could post source code of example with this issue, then I will debug it and check if I was right - but after Christmas :) Sorry that you're waiting for answer. Happy Christmas! :)

Comment: I debugged and confirmed that it is caused by RDD laziness. The issue with RDD laziness is  it is triggered multiple times for every message  for the same call to RDD.count() and to

Comment: That's fine :) Maybe it depends also on source, because I couldn't reproduce it on socket source and that's why I didn't post an answer - I didn't want to tell you anything wrong ;)

Comment: To elaborate on my previous response, This issue with RDD's laziness about multiple invocations to map's function is say there are 100 msgs 
1. for 2 calls to  RDD.count() in foreachRD => 200 invocations to map's function.
2. for Iterator.next in foreachPartition, => another 100 invocations to map's function.

=> 300 invocations total to map's function.  RDD's laziness makes sense for the first 100 invocations for the 100 messages. But I'd expect RDD's laziness to optimize and skip the subsequent duplicate map's call invocations for the same 100 messages, without using cache() explicitly.

Comment: You can do `rdd.cache()` in `foreachRDD` and `rdd.unpersist()` in the ending of `foreachRDD`. It would cache RDD only for current batch - helpful if your job will be very long-running ;)