# Unnecessary Extra forEachPartition causing extra time to complete the Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'll be getting data from `Hbase` within a TimeRange. So, I divided the time range into chunks and scanning the columns from `Hbase` within the chunked TimeRange like

Suppose, I have a TimeRange from Jun to Aug, I divide them into Weekly, which gives 8 weeks TimeRange List.
From that, I will scan the columns of `Hbase` via `repartition` & `mappartition` like

```
sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(chunkedTimeRange.toList).repartition(noOfCores).mapPartitions{
    // Scan Cols of Hbase Logic
    // This gives DF as output
}
```

I'll get DF from the above and Do some filter to that DF using mappartition and foreachPartition like

```
df.mapPartitions{
  rows => {
    rows.toList.par.foreach(
      cols => {
        json.filter(condition).foreach(//code)
        anotherJson.filter(condition).foreach(//code)
      }
    )
  }
  // returns DF
}
```

This DF has been used by other methods, Since mapparttions are lazy. I called an action after the above like

```
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df.foreachPartition((x: Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) => x: Unit)
```

This `forEachPartition` unnecessarily executing twice. One stage taking it around 2.5 min (128 tasks) and Other one 40s (200 tasks) which is not necessary.
200 is the mentioned value in spark config
`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200`.

How to avoid this unnecessary `foreachPartition`? Is there any way still I can make it better in terms of performance?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171548/why-foreachpartition-function-make-duplicate-invocation-to-map-function-for-ever). Unfortunately, I didn't get much Information from that.

**Screenshot of foreachPartitions happening twice for same DF**
[image: screenshot of foreachPartitions]

If any clarification needed, please mention in comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to "reuse" the persisted Dataframe:

```scala
val df2 = df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df2.foreachPartition((x: Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) => x: Unit)
```

Otherwise when running the `foreachPartition`, it runs on a DF which has not been persisted and it's doing every step of the DF computation again.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I implemented as you suggested and that makes sense to store persisted df to another var but I'm still getting unnecessary foreachPartition twice for the same df as mentioned in question

Comment: Maybe you should give more info on what make you say it is executed twice.

Comment: I didn't observed `Shuffle write` and `Shuffle Read` columns in the haddop UI. Once it is persisted (write to memory), will it call one more `foreachPartition` to read automatically? If yes, I misunderstood that `foreachPartition` is happening twice.. Anyways added image in the question for more clarification..